# jQuery - IF then Remove class on .hover

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery function:

```
$(function(){
            if ($(".menu li").hasClass("active")) {
                    $(".active").css("margin-top", "6px");
              }
        });
```

This is applied to a CSS/jQuery menu, which expands and contracts when each menu item is hovered over. The onClick event adds a `margin-top of 6px` to give the impressions of a button depress.

I'm then using PHP to detect which page the user is visiting to add an `.active` class to the relevant menu item.

The question, the .active class should remain in place **until** the user hovers over a different menu item. At which point the `.active` class should be removed from this element - As the `.active` class is reused on the `.hover` events.

Here is the basic HTML Markup:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li>
<div class="inner">
<div class="button"><img src="images/insightbutton.png" /></div>
<div class="description">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="inner">
<div class="button"><img src="images/insightbutton.png" /></div>
<div class="description">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

How can I keep the .active class applied to the active menu item, but remove it when .inner is hovered over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$(".menu li.active").addclass("onPage");
$(".menu li").hover(function() {
  $(".menu li.active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass("active");
  $(".menu li.onPage").addClass("active");
});
```

This code does the following:

- Assigns a placeholder class to the original `active` (assigned by your PHP).
- On hover, removes the `active` class from all `<li>` siblings and sets the hovered to one to `active`.
- On leaving hover, it removes `active` from itself and selects the placeholder and restores active to the original (the page they're on).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply select the `div` which has the `active` class, and remove the class:

```
$('div.inner').hover(function() {
    $('div.active').removeClass('active');
});
```